# Parse.com query string variable value

Tags: android, variables, android-asynctask, parse-platform

I'm trying to query a parse.com table based on the value of a string variable and not a string..

The below works and is an example of what is being searched for.

```
query.whereEqualTo("movieCategory", "Action");
```

But instead of this I've stored a variable from a Spinner..

```
query.whereEqualTo("movieCategory", derrick);
```

I can access this variable just fine from other methods.. except the parse query

Imagine the variable "derrick" contains another string such as "Thriller"

Any ideas on how I can achieve this instead of being constrained to what i specifically want to search for?

The application crashes and complains of a **"android.view.WindowLeaked:"**

Will I need to do it as if derrick.equals("action") else if derrick.equals("romance") etc...? because when I tried that the same crash occured.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

This is my DashboardActivity.class where I'm getting the variable...

```
public String getCategory() {
        Spinner spinCategory = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_category);
        String whatCategory = spinCategory.getSelectedItem().toString();

        return whatCategory;
    }
```

Here is the whole try method from the ResultsActivity.class

```
// RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
    private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ResultsActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            DashboardActivity  cls2= new DashboardActivity();
            cls2.getCategory();
            String derrick = cls2.getCategory();

            // Create the array
            movielist = new ArrayList<movieListGroup>();

            try {
                // Locate the class table named "Movie" in Parse.com
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                        "Movie");

                query.whereEqualTo("movieCategory", derrick);

//                if (derrick.equals ("Action")) {
//                    query.whereEqualTo("movieCategory", "Action");
//
//                } else if (derrick.equals ("Romance")) {
//                    query.whereEqualTo("movieCategory", "Romance");
//
//                } else if (derrick.equals("Comedy")) {
//                    query.whereEqualTo("movieCategory", "Comedy");
//
//                }

                //query.whereEqualTo("movieCategory", "Romance");
                query.orderByAscending("movieNum");

                ob = query.find();
                for (ParseObject movie : ob) {
                    // Locate images in flag column
                    ParseFile image = (ParseFile) movie.get("movieImage");

                    movieListGroup map = new movieListGroup();
                    map.setNumber((String) movie.get("movieNum"));
                    map.setCategory((String) movie.get("movieCategory"));
                    map.setTitle((String) movie.get("movieTitle"));
                    map.setDescription((String) movie.get("movieDesc"));
                    map.setDirector((String) movie.get("movieDirector"));
                    map.setFlag(image.getUrl());
                    movielist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(ResultsActivity.this,
                    movielist);
            // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

And the log cat.....

```
03-13 17:40:52.575    5980-5980/com.example.derrick.moveed E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.derrick.moveed.ResultsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{339cf210 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-1026,288} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
            at com.example.derrick.moveed.ResultsActivity$RemoteDataTask.onPreExecute(ResultsActivity.java:77)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at com.example.derrick.moveed.ResultsActivity.onCreate(ResultsActivity.java:61)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
03-13 17:40:59.376    5980-6003/com.example.derrick.moveed I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 5980 SIG: 9
```

Comment: I do not think `android.view.WindowLeaked` crashes the app. It is probably something else that is causing the crash

Comment: @hoomi Maybe you're right but if i search directly for a string like "Action" my function works..

Comment: @ci_ "derrick" is a variable that contains the value of a spinner from the previous activity. I can access it just fine in other methods too.

Comment: try using `derrick+""` instead? it force it translate into a string

Comment: can you post your logcat.

Comment: Also post the code where you set the value of the `derrick` variable.

Comment: @SurenderKumar Hi, I've posted it.

Comment: I can't see how that would be related to the query variable.  In my experience, those errors are usually from trying to open a dialog with the wrong context.  I would search on that error message and try some suggestions you find (assuming you haven't already).  Instead of `new ProgressDialog(ResultsActivity.this)`, try `new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext())` for example.

Comment: @nasch Hi, I don't think its the dialog as if I search for a direct query It functions as expected aka closes the dialog and displays the list of results..

Comment: If you use a string literal it works, and if you use the variable it fails?  That makes no sense...  Have you actually checked the value of the variable?

Comment: @nasch Ive figured out its the " DashboardActivity  cls2= new DashboardActivity();
            cls2.getCategory();" bit that makes it crash but its the code I need to obtain the string.. How else do I avoid it doing so :(

Answer (score 1):

You can't just instantiate an Activity with new and then use findViewById(). If your AsyncTask is part of your Activity you should be able to call DashboardActivity.this. getCategory() instead.

Just saw that there is another Activity involved that your not showing and I'm not sure how ResultActivity is started from DashboardActivity. You may have to pass the category as an extra when you start ResultActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this some it helped me i also faced the same error.

```
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
     ProgressDialog mProgressDialog ;
    Context c;
     public RemoteDataTask(Context c){
    this.c =c;
    }
     @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Create a progressdialog
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ResultsActivity.this);
                // Set progressdialog title
    ........
    }

    }
```

Now on calling this task :

```
new RemoteDataTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
```